# How to store error Log to database in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, error-logging

I would like to store system error log to a database by extending the existing CI_Log class. So far this is what i have done

```
class MY_Logger extends CI_Log{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function write_log($level='error', $msg, $php_error = FALSE){

        $result = parent::write_log($level, $msg, $php_error);
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->library('user_agent');
        if ($result == TRUE && strtoupper($level) == 'ERROR') {

            $gmtoffset = 60*60*5;
            $post = array(
                'log_type' => $level,
                'log_message' => $msg,
                'log_php_message' => $php_error,
                'log_ip_origin' => $this->input->ip_address(),
                'log_user_agent' => $this->agent->agent_string(),
                'log_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time() + $gmtoffset)
            );

            $ci->db->insert('system_log', $post);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

and i have the following configured in autoload.php and config.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc', 'user_agent');
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

However when i test it, it does not store the error to database (although, it displays and writes the log properly)

Can any one point out what i missed here?

ps:

Having changed the code so it extends CI_Exceptions does not work as well:

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line){

        //$result = parent::write_log($level, $msg, $php_error);
        $ci =& get_instance();
        //if ($result == TRUE && strtoupper($level) == 'ERROR') {

            $gmtoffset = 60*60*5;
            $post = array(
                'log_type' => $severity,
                'log_message' => $message,
                'log_php_message' => $line,
                'log_ip_origin' => $ci->input->ip_address(),
                'log_user_agent' => $ci->agent->agent_string(),
                'log_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time() + $gmtoffset)
            );

            $ci->db->insert('system_log', $post);
        //}
        parent::log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
        //return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: any error it throws?\

Comment: Is your logger in libraries folder? Try renaming it MY_Log (or whatever prefix you have set in config instead of MY_)

Comment: @LolCoder i tested it by creating a deliberate error of inserting data to a non-existing table.

Comment: @package yes my logger class is inside application/libraries/logger.php, there is one thing that i am not sure of, is how to load this library. Because normally if i want to load my own library i need to explicitly specify it inside my controller

Comment: @package both renaming logger.php -> MY_Logger.php and renaming the class Logger -> class MY_Logger does not work either.

Comment: The filename should be log.php and classname shoud be MY_Log.php, not MY_Logger.php. Read here more about extending CI libraries: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: Well now i am confused, after reading the "Extending Native Libraries" section in the user guide it says to extend the native library, both the class name and the filename must be prefixed with MY_ (or whatever i configure it to inside config.php). Unless if i want to replace the native library entirely with my version (which in this case is not what i want). Anyway i'll try your suggestion (it doesn't hurt anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I tried this a while back and concluded that one should not reference the CI instance in MY_Log, since it's not yet available (or not always constructed yet).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is happening because the log_message() function - which utilizes the Log library - is being used before the CI_Controller singleton is available.

You’ll likely need to add a check to see if the CI_Controller class is available yet, and if it is, then use the get_instance() function. Then, when using $CI, you’ll have to make sure it’s set appropriately first (or just do it inside the first check’s if statement if you aren’t utilizing the constructor to assign $CI).

Chances are you’re trying to log errors that occur in your controllers, which would mean the DB functions would be available by then. You’ll just be without DB logging for those earlier debug messages that occur when some Core files initialize.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with order of loading.  My goal was to redirect CI logging to MonoLog and to have any errors emailed to me.  I wanted to use the library framework that was already in place to load Monolog and SwiftMail, but that isn't available.

I loaded the config settings from get_config in CI_Log, but this only includes values from config.php (not from any other config files).  I used the get_config function as a base to create another function to load other config files.  This then allowed me to load my email settings.  I then created new loaders for Monolog and Swiftmail.  Its a little messy, but it works.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

include_once APPPATH . 'libraries/Swift_Mail/swift_required.php';
require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/common/ClassLoader.php';

use MyApp\Common\ClassLoader,
Monolog\Logger,
Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler,
Monolog\Handler\SwiftMailerHandler,
 Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MY_Log extends CI_Log  {

/** @var \Swift_Mailer  */
private $mailer;

/** @var  $logger LoggerInterface */
protected  $logger;

private $cfg;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $masterConfig = &get_config(); //This is a config array, not the CI Config object
    $emailConfig = $this->GetConfig('email');
    $this->cfg = array_merge($masterConfig, $emailConfig);

    $this->InitMailer();
    $this->InitLogger();
}

/**
 * There is no exposed CI way to load the email config file, so this allows us to load it.
 * The logic is based on the get_config function in CI.
 * @param $configName
 * @return null
 */
function GetConfig($configName)
{
    $config = null;

    // Is the config file in the environment folder?
    if ( ! defined('ENVIRONMENT') OR ! file_exists($file_path = APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/'.$configName.'.php'))
    {
        $file_path = APPPATH.'config/config.php';
    }

    // Fetch the config file
    if ( ! file_exists($file_path))
    {
        exit('The configuration file does not exist.');
    }

    require($file_path);

    // Does the $config array exist in the file?
    if ( ! isset($config) OR ! is_array($config))
    {
        exit('Your config file does not appear to be formatted correctly.');
    }

    return $config;
}

/**
 * This mirrors the init in the SwiftMail Loader.  This is required b/c
 * libraries are not loaded at this point.
 */
protected function InitMailer()
{
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance
        ($this->cfg['smtp_host'],
            $this->cfg['smtp_port']);

    $transport->setTimeout(20); //Amazon Internal Timeout of 5s, just giving a buffer

    if(array_key_exists('smtp_user',$this->cfg))
    {
        $transport->setUsername($this->cfg['smtp_user']);
    }

    if(array_key_exists('smtp_pass',$this->cfg))
    {
        $transport->setPassword($this->cfg['smtp_pass']);
    }

    if(array_key_exists('smtp_crypto',$this->cfg))
    {
        $transport->setEncryption($this->cfg['smtp_crypto']);
    }

    /** @var  $mailer Swift_Mailer*/
    $this->mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
}

/**
 * Setup monolog.
 */
protected function InitLogger()
{
    $loader = new ClassLoader("Psr", APPPATH . 'libraries');
    $loader->register();

    $loader = new ClassLoader("Monolog", APPPATH . 'libraries');
    $loader->register();

    $logLevel = Logger::ERROR;

    /* CI Error levels
     *  |   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
        |   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
        |   2 = Debug Messages
        |   3 = Informational Messages
        |   4 = All Messages
     */

    switch($this->cfg['log_threshold'])
    {
        case 0:
            $logLevel = Logger::ERROR; //We still want errors.
            break;
        case 1:
            $logLevel = Logger::INFO;
            break;
        case 2:
            $logLevel = Logger::DEBUG;
            break;
        case 3:
            $logLevel = Logger::INFO;
            break;
        case 4:
            $logLevel = Logger::DEBUG;
            break;
    }

    /** @var  $message Swift_Message*/
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('MyApp Error - '.ENVIRONMENT)
        ->setFrom($this->cfg['FROM_ADDR'])
        ->setTo($this->cfg['ERROR_ADDR']);

    $swiftMailHandler = new SwiftMailerHandler($this->mailer, $message, Logger::ERROR);


    $this->logger = new Logger('myapp');
    $this->logger->pushHandler(new RotatingFileHandler(APPPATH.'logs/myapp.log', 0, $logLevel, true, 0666));
    $this->logger->pushHandler($swiftMailHandler);
}


public function write_log($level = 'error', $msg, $php_error = FALSE)
{
    parent::write_log($level, $msg, $php_error);

    if($level === 'error')
    {
        $this->logger->error($msg);
    }
    elseif($level === 'debug')
    {
        $this->logger->debug($msg);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->logger->info($msg);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

@Jeremy In one of your comments, you have mentioned that your logger class is stored inside the **libraries** folder. Instead, it should be placed under the **core** folder with the name as MY_Log.php. For more details refer to the following link:

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html#extending-core-class

The only issue was with the file naming convention and placing it in the wrong folder. As for your code, I have tested it at my end and it works properly. I know its an old question but was knowing the solution for the same so shared it.